# What are android.testVariants good for?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So, the new Gradle build system knows of `android.applicationVariants` for app modules and `android.libraryVariants` for library modules with which one can, for example, easily get information about existing, valid build variants in multi-dimension flavor setups.

The [official documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manipulating-tasks) however lists a third domain collection, `android.testVariants`, that seems to exist for both, app and library modules.

What is the exact purpose of this collection? What is it good for?

Comment: On a more or less related note, can it be that there are no `testVariants` anymore with Android Gradle plugin 2.2.1? At least my code relying on `testVariants` does not work anymore, and [these docs](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.TestExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.TestExtension:applicationVariants) contain `applicationVariants` instead for the `TestExtension`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define tests for a **multi-flavors** project.

You can create sourceSets for each flavor used in the test:

**android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor1** is defined in:

```
src/androidTestFlavor1/
```

**android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor2** is defined in:

```
src/androidTestFlavor2/
```

**Each flavor has its own task to run tests: `androidTest<VariantName>`**.

For instance:

```
androidTestFlavor1Debug
androidTestFlavor2Debug
```

And, you can define these testVariant for all modules, app or library modules.

Comment: Understood I correctly that this collection is then a pre-filtered list of variants I have `androidTest`s for, i.e. it might be equal or a subset of variants of all `applicationVariants` or `libraryVariants`?

Comment: Yes as I know you can define different tests for the same or a subset of variants.